# General strategy for pattern matching on the Flow Parser AST

Tags: ocaml, flowtype

I'm working on a project which uses the flow parser. I'm a bit new to OCaml, so all of the parameterized types are making my head spin. Given this simple example:

```ml
utop # Parser_flow.program "let x;";;
- : Loc.t Ast.program * (Loc.t * Parse_error.t) list =
(({Loc.source = None; start = {Loc.line = 1; column = 0; offset = 0};
   _end = {Loc.line = 1; column = 6; offset = 6}},
  [({Loc.source = None; start = {Loc.line = 1; column = 0; offset = 0};
     _end = {Loc.line = 1; column = 6; offset = 6}},
    Ast.Statement.VariableDeclaration
     {Ast.Statement.VariableDeclaration.declarations =
       [({Loc.source = None; start = {Loc.line = 1; column = 4; offset = 4};
          _end = {Loc.line = 1; column = 5; offset = 5}},
         {Ast.Statement.VariableDeclaration.Declarator.id =
           ({Loc.source = None; start = {Loc.line = 1; column = 4; offset = 4};
             _end = {Loc.line = 1; column = 5; offset = 5}},
            Ast.Pattern.Identifier
             {Ast.Pattern.Identifier.name =
               ({Loc.source = None;
                 start = {Loc.line = 1; column = 4; offset = 4};
                 _end = {Loc.line = 1; column = 5; offset = 5}},
                "x");
              typeAnnotation = None; optional = false});
          init = None})];
      kind = Ast.Statement.VariableDeclaration.Let})],
  []),
 [])
```

Considering just the `Loc.t Ast.program` part: so `Ast.program` is parameterized by `Loc.t`, I think I follow that far:

`type nonrec 'M program = 'M * 'M Ast.Statement.t list * 'M Ast.Comment.t list`

Now considering just the list of statements, suppose I wanted to step through and print something for every `VariableDeclaration`, for example. How would I go about matching that construct? Could I do something like:

```ml
(** x is an element of Loc.t Ast.Statement.t list *)
let match_test x =
  match x with
    | (Loc.t l, Ast.Statement.VariableDeclaration b) -> print_string "declaration!"
    | _ -> print_string "no declaration!"
```

Thanks for any pointers/help!

Comment: In general, wildcards (underscores) in pattern matches can help make them less cluttered. Try only matching on the parts of the structure that you are interested in. Take a look at the code in `statement.ml` and `flow_ast_mapper.ml` in the Flow codebase for examples showing how we pattern match on the parts of the AST that are relevant. It's much more readable than the complicated type definition might suggest.

Comment: @NatMote Just what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OCaml pattern matching, together with algebraic data types, comprise a powerful data language that enables easy encoding of complex data structures as well as processing them. That makes OCaml a nice tool for analyzing structural data. Surprisingly, pattern matching is not very common in mainstream languages, so this concept sometimes confuses people. Let me try to explain it using simple examples, and then we can move towards something more complex.

To construct data we need to define data constructors. Data constructors denote different possible ways to create values of a given type. That is why they are also commonly called variants. For example,

```
type image = 
 | Circle of int
 | Rectangle of int * int
 | Row of image * image
 | Column of image * image
 | Layer of image * image
```

and a circle of radius 10 is denoted as `Circle 10` and we can put one circle on top of another using `Layer (Circle 10, Circle 5)`, e.g.,

```
# let eye = Layer (Circle 10, Circle 5);;
val eye : image = Layer (Circle 10, Circle 5)
```

We now have an object of type `image` named `eye`. The OCaml toplevel is nice to print it for us and as humans we can easily see its layout. But as programmers, we need to analyze it. We need to deconstruct the image to see from what parts it is built. To deconstruct an object we use the same syntax that we used to construct it, except that we write the structure on the left of the equality sign and the object that we deconstruct on the right side, e.g.,

```
let Layer (Circle 10, Circle 5) = eye
```

If we will type it in the OCaml toplevel, it will agree with us, but will raise a warning, like, what if the `eye` object is no a layer of two circles? Or what of circles have different radii? In that case, we couldn't deconstruct the eye object and our program will fail. So we need somehow to be able to consider all possibilities, first of all, let's learn how to match with eyes of any sizes, e.g.,

```
let Layer (Circle _, Circle _) = eye
```

this pattern will match with an eye of any size. We used a wildcard pattern `_` that says "match with whatever is there I don't care." But what if we care, what if we want to match with any size, but still be able to know them? This is where the binding matching comes into play, we can use variables instead of data constructors in our pattern, and when a match happens, variables will refer to the objects in the corresponding places, e.g.,

```
 # let Layer (Circle outer, Circle inner) = eye
 val outer : int = 10
 val inner : int = 5
```

and now we can use `outer` and `inner` variables, e.g.,

```
 assert (outer > inner)
```

Now, instead of matching with only one eye with the given configuration, we are able to match with an infinite number of different eyes, but still only eyes (i.e., two layers of circles).

It's finally the time to introduce the match expression,

```
# let what_is_that = 
    match eye with
    | Layer (Circle _, Circle _) -> "an eye"
    | _ -> "I don't know
val what_is_that : string = "an eye"
```

Now OCaml is finally happy since we analyzed all possible images, so no warnings are emitted. In general, the match expression is having the form

```
 match <exp> with
 | <pat1> -> <e1>
 | <pat2> -> <e2>
 ...
 | <patN> -> <eN>
```

When it is evaluated the object that the expression `<exp>` denotes is analyzed and all patterns are applied in a sequence until a matching pattern is found, the expression on the right of the matching pattern is then evaluated and it can use any variables bound in this pattern. The result of this expression then becomes the result of the whole `match` expression. To solidify this knowledge, let's write something meaningful, like a function that computes a bounding box of an image, e.g.,

```
let rec bounding_box image = match image with
  | Circle r -> 2*r,2*r
  | Rectangle (h,w) -> h,w
  | Row (left,right) ->
    let hl,wl = bounding_box left
    and hr,wr = bounding_box right in
    max hl hr, wl + wr
  | Column (top,bot) ->
    let ht,wt = bounding_box top
    and hb,wb = bounding_box bot in
    ht + hb, max wt wb
  | Layer (x,y) ->
    let hx,wx = bounding_box x
    and hy,wy = bounding_box y in
    max hx hy, max wx wy
```

And here is how it works,

```
# bounding_box eye;;
- : int * int = (20, 20)

# bounding_box (Row (eye,eye));;
- : int * int = (20, 40)
```

Besides, what is `(20,20)`? It is called a tuple and is a builtin way of constructing pairs, triples, and so on. We could, of course define our own pairs, like

```
type pair = Pair of int * int
```

or even make it a polymorphic data structure, e.g.,

```
type ('a,'b) = Pair of 'a * 'b
```

and then repeat the same for Triple, Quadruple, and so on. But designers of the language decided that it would be too cumbersome, since the arity of a tuple is easily described by the number of commas, so we can construct tuples without any specific named constructors. Otherwise, tuples play by the same rules and constructed and deconstructed with the same syntax, e.g.,

```
let 4, 3 = 2*2, 4-1
```

Parentheses are optional but are often used, since the precedence of the comma operator is very low. Therefore, people tend to use parentheses always, e.g.,

```
let (4, 3) = (2*2, 4-1)
```

While tuples are very convenient, the lack of names makes it very easy to forget which element means what. Like I'm not even sure that the `bounding_box` function above is correct and I didn't confuse width with the height somewhere. Moreover, it is not even obvious what this function returns. So here come records. Records are tuples with named fields. E.g.,

```
type box = {height : int; width : int}
```

And now we can use the new `box` type to rewrite the `bounding_box` function. It would be also a good to use it to construct our rectangles, e.g., we can redefine the `Rectangle` constructor as `| Rectangle of box`. But I will let this as an exercise to the reader.

I hope, that this information should be enough to start using pattern matching without fear. You can also consider looking [at this example](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/plugins/frontc_parser/frontc_parser_main.ml) for some inspiration.